# launch app only on a new screen with android

Tags: android, screen

I would like to create an app on android 5.1 which can be displayed on a new screen plugged to the phone but not on the phone screen.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, how or where can I find some information?

Comment: The "Hello" was not display on the message, so I tell you "Hi" here  ;)

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more explicit.
My question is: how can we make an app that is displayed on a second screen while the phone stay normally usable ?